# Push multi-dimensional array with new key

Tags: php, arrays

I want each time a file is called, to make a new sub-array. So say if I have a URL like `http://example.com?name=[INPUT]` , every time it calls it will add a new element to the array. With `$users` being the main array. EA:

```
$users[0][name] = "John"    
$users[1][name] = "Sally"
```

Each call to the input will create a new `$users[INCRIMENTAL_KEY][name]` value.

Comment: Where you say incremental key, you know that `$array[]` will create a new array key, incrementally?

Comment: Do you want this array to remember EVERY time this has happened across many users and many days?

Comment: It is impossible to know exactly what you want from this question. Either add some detail to the question as per above request or accept one of the anaswers. Otherwise I will suggest closing this question as _unclear what you are asking_.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be

```
$user[]['name'] = $name;
```

Although if all you are storing is a single item it would be even simpler to do

```
$user[] = $name;
```

Although if you want to keep this information across page executions and not be effected by WHO is running the page, you are going to have to keep the information in a database and just add a new row to a table each time the script is run.

Comment: How does this work when in the example there is only one value per request for `name`?

Comment: @scrowler Sorry, not sure I understand? Have I said something dumb?

Comment: I mean there's only one `$_GET['name']` - so your array at run time will only every have one element in it?

Comment: @scrowler Yup! And using session will only work for a single user and not across all current users of the site. _The question is rather vague so neither of us know exactly what the OP actually wants_ Guess we should both have kept our powder dry untill we got more information from the OP, but he is not answering any questions!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a persistent way to track the array's data, whether that be sessions, database or files (depends on how long you want persistence for and whether it should be public or per-user).

Session example:

```
session_start();

// Initialise an empty array
if (empty($_SESSION['users'])) {
    $_SESSION['users'] = [];
}

// Add each name to the session array
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['users'][] = ['name' => $_GET['name']];
}
```

Session would of course be per-user and per-session. You could use cookies and/or sessions for a longer persistence per-user, or use flatfile/database storage for more control and non-ending persistence.